# Modify thumbprint value in <system.identityModel> in web.config programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, var, trusted-web-activity, identitymodel

I have a app where I need to change the thumbprint without open the web.config file.

```
<system.identityModel>  
 <identityConfiguration>  
    <securityTokenHandlers>  
      <securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>  
        <issuerNameRegistry>  
          <trustedIssuers>  
            <add thumbprint=xs:string name=xs:string>  
            <clear>  
            <remove thumbprint=xs:string>  
          </trustedIssuers>  
        </issuerNameRegistry>  
      </securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>  
    </securityTokenHandlers>  
  </identityConfiguration>  
</system.identityModel>
```

someone added below code from another question but cant get it to work.

```
  var configuration = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration();
        configuration.AudienceRestriction.AudienceMode = AudienceUriMode.Always;
        configuration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri("https://application.local/"));
        configuration.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.ChainTrust;
        configuration.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
        configuration.CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.ChainTrust;
        var registry = new ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry();
        registry.AddTrustedIssuer("<Certificate Thumbprint>", "ADFS Signing - adfs.example.local");
        configuration.IssuerNameRegistry = registry;
        //SecurityTokenHandlers = SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenHandlerCollection(configuration);
        SecurityTokenHandlers = System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers;
```

Comment: Please be more specific! What are you trying to do? with what tools? what have you tried? what is the error? at which point you need help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.